# store function into variable that expects parameters

Tags: mysql, sql

So given the following example query

```
SET @first_day_of_current_year = MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), 1);
SET @current_month = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE);

SELECT *
FROM document
WHERE
    created >= (SELECT DATE_ADD(@first_day_of_current_year, INTERVAL @current_month - 2 MONTH))
AND 
    created < (SELECT DATE_ADD(@first_day_of_current_year, INTERVAL @current_month - 1 MONTH));
```

I want to fetch all documents created in a range of two dates. As you can see I put some calculations into variables because I can reuse them in the `WHERE` clause. Further those calculations only differ by one value, the month at the end. So the calculation could also be

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(@first_day_of_current_year, INTERVAL @current_month - x MONTH)
```

Is there a way I could create a temporary function for that calculation that expects a parameter? Like so (pseudo syntax)

```
SET @calculator = amountOfMonths => SELECT DATE_ADD(@first_day_of_current_year, INTERVAL @current_month - {{amountOfMonths}} MONTH);
```

This would not improve the performance but it might improve the readability because things get reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use stored procedures to accomplish what you are looking for. Then you can pass it a parameter that you set as an OUT parameter, and use it after the procedure has been called.

Something like this;

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fetch_documents;
CREATE PROCEDURE fetch_documents(OUT foo integer)

BEGIN
    --here you set your out parameter equal to the calculation
end;
```

To call you can do something like;

```
CALL fetch_documents(@foo);

SELECT @foo;
```

Hope this helps!